# How to send parameters to the middleware functions in Express routing?

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a MEAN project where we have some defined api routes like this:

```
//products.controller.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const m = require('../../middlewares');

router.get('/products', [m.functionA, m.functionB, m.functionC], getProducts);
router.post('/products', [m.functionA, m.functionB, m.functionC], addNewProduct);

module.exports = router;

function getProducts(req, res) {
    //code
}

function addNewProduct(req, res) {
    //code
}
```

..............

```
//middlewares.js

function functionA(req, res, next) {
    //code
}

function functionB(req, res, next) {
    //code
}

function functionC(req, res, next) {
    //code
}
```

Here now I can access req, res and next. How can I pass custom parameters to these middleware functions?

I looked over some SO questions and other articles and found that I can do like this:

```
[m.functionA('data'), m.functionB('data'), m.functionC('data')]
```

But on doing this, I get error that req, res are not defined.

Can anyone please help/suggest how to implement this.
Let me know if any other details need to be added here.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use `m.functionA('data')`, a common paradigm amongst Express middleware is to create a function that takes the parameter as an argument, *and returns a middleware function*:

```
function functionA(customParameter) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // code
  }
}
```

The inner function (the one being returned) has access to `customParameter` as well as `req/res/next`.

Comment: I´m trying to build an async function based on the example you provided, but it´s not working. Can you give a tip on how it would look? I´m getting an error message like: requires a callback function but got a [object Promise]

Comment: Never mind. Got the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557486/express-pass-parameter-to-async-middleware)

Answer (score -4):

You could call the function with the arguments you like you using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
function getProducts(list) {
  console.log(list);
}

getProducts.apply(null,['foo','bar'])
```