# Express pass parameter to async middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I have a synchronous middleware to authorize role. It's set up like this:

Route:

```
router.get("/test", [authorizeRole("tier1", "tier2")], function(req, res) {})
```

Middleware:

```
module.exports = function authorizeRoles(...role) {
    return (request, response, next) => {
        //authorize
    };
};
```

This is working. Now i want to change my middleware to make it async.

I can't figure out how to make the middleware async. I tried:

```
module.exports = async function authorizeRoles(...role) {
    return await (request, response, next) => {
        //authorize
    };
};

module.exports = async function authorizeRoles(...role) {
    return await async (request, response, next) => {
        //authorize
    };
};
```

But nothing works.

How can i make the middleware async?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understood your question. To use `await` you need to declare your function using the `async` keyword, so this should work

```
module.exports = function authorizeRoles(...role) {
    return async (request, response, next) => {
        // now you can use `await` here
    };
};
```

Comment: Yes, i get "route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise]"

Comment: You need to replace `async function authorizeRoles` by `function authorizeRoles`?

Comment: That works, thanks, but now however the "await"-block isnt resolved until the code in the router function is completed.. strange

Comment: @Tobol i know this was forever ago, but did you ever solve this?