# How to make ExpressJS middleware to accept parameters

Tags: node.js, express, parameters, callback, middleware

What I want to get is adding a unified processing to control the access of different resources. Either  accessControlMiddlewareA or accessControlMiddlewareB style will be much appreciated!

```js
router.post('/pathA', accessControlMiddlewareA("sectionA", req, res, next) => {
    //....
})
router.post('/pathB', accessControlMiddlewareA("sectionB", req, res, next) => {
    //....
})
```

or,

```js
router.post('/pathA', accessControlMiddlewareB("sectionA", (req, res, next) => {
    //....
}))
router.post('/pathB', accessControlMiddlewareB("sectionB", (req, res, next) => {
    //....
}))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send parameters to the middleware functions in Express routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240248/how-to-send-parameters-to-the-middleware-functions-in-express-routing)

Comment: This a duplicate question: answer can be found in these posts:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240248/how-to-send-parameters-to-the-middleware-functions-in-express-routing

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557486/express-pass-parameter-to-async-middleware

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write a function that returns the middleware:

```
function accessControlMiddlewareA ( section ) {
    // now we return the actual middleware:
    return (req, res, next) {
        // use `section` in here
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
router.post('/pathA', accessControlMiddlewareA("sectionA"));
```

---

If you need to do some post processing after the middleware just add another anonymous middleware:

```
router.post('/pathA', accessControlMiddlewareA("sectionA"));
router.post('/pathA', (req, res, next) => {
    // additional logic here
});
```

or the shorter version:

```
// same as the code above:
router.post('/pathA', accessControlMiddlewareA("sectionA"), (req, res, next) => {
    // additional logic here
});
```

Comment: Hello, this question is already asked and answered in a few questions, so better to flag this question as duplicate.